# swift: collectionView section

Tags: ios, swift

I have 7 section in `collectionView`. I want to show image in all section except first and last.

I use this code to do it:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if sectionNumber == 0 {
        //hide image
    } else {
        //show image
    }

    if sectionNumber == 6 {
        //hide image
    } else {
        //show image
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        sectionNumber = indexPath.section
        print("indexPath.section\(indexPath.section)")
}
```

But code doesn't work. When I scroll to last section my image hides in 6 section(5 in code because first section == 0). And if I scroll to first section my image not hides.

Also I have second variant of code. In this variant all works fine except when I scroll to first section my image hides in second.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let currentlyVisibleSection = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.map { $0.section }.min()!

        if currentlyVisibleSection < 5 {
            let scrollToSection = currentlyVisibleSection + 1
            //show image
        }

        if currentlyVisibleSection == 5 {
            let scrollToSection = currentlyVisibleSection + 1
            //hide image
        }

        if currentlyVisibleSection != 1 {
            let scrollToSection = currentlyVisibleSection - 1
            //show image
        }

        if currentlyVisibleSection == 1 {
            let scrollToSection = currentlyVisibleSection - 1
            //hide image
        }
}
```

**Update**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            print("firstSection")
        }

        if (indexPath.section + 1) == dataModel.count {
            print("lastSection")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try reloadData() after scrollViewDidEndDecelarating?

I try to propose another approach:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            guard let cell = cell as? CollectionViewCell else {return}

            switch indexPath.section {
            case 0,6: //in assumption number of sections = 7
                cell.myImage.isHidden = true
            default:
                cell.myImage.isHidden = false
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get same result

Comment: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: Have you try to remove override ?

Comment: It is works. But I have a on problem I use this to animation for image `UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                           options: [], animations: {
                            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })` But my image appears and disasters with a slight delay

Comment: But if I scroll fist time I haven't a delay.

Comment: Refactor your view animation method and put the method into closure dispatch, something like this: DispatchQueue.main.async { //your animation method// }

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is hiding behind `//hide image` and `//show image`, but why not to move the logic into the cell itself? Every time when the cell is displayed it reuse the old one and `cellForItemAt` gets called. So either there or in the cell you can determine what row you are displaying.

So you can create a simple function where you'd determine whether this row is first or last.

```
func displayImage(on indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return false
    }

    if (indexPath.section + 1) == dataModel.count {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

`dataModel` would have to be a two levels array

`let dataModel = [["item1", "item2", "item3"], ["item4", "item5", "item6"]]`

where each sub array would represent one section.

Comment: I updated question. And add under Update title how to I use your code.  When I scroll from first section to last I get `lastSection` in second section. When I scroll from last section to first. I get `lastSection` in third section and `firstSection` in second section.

Comment: If this happens, it means that your `dataModel` does not have the correct structure. Can you update your question with a print of your `dataModel`?

Comment: You can print it in Xcode into the console and copy/paste it to your question.

Comment: I meant where should I paste `dataModel ` in my code after which line?

Comment: Well you should assemble the `dataModel` before rendering or after some async call, so whenever the model is complete

Comment: Sorry. I do not quite understand how I should do this. Could you give an example please?

Comment: I use your code. But I change your array on my array because I need to use it. dataModel = [["item","item","item"],["item","item","item"],["item","item","item"],["item","item","item"],["item","item","item"],["item","item","item"],["item","item","item"]]. I get "firstSection" in second section and `lastSection ` in six section. I have 7 sections.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong on your side, so I've created a very simple project on [Github](https://github.com/MartinPrusa/CollectionViewSectionTest-iOS), please review it and lemme know if you'll need anything

Comment: It is works. But I have several problems. **First**. I not have image in cell class. I have image in super view. And I use this code for hide: `if !displayImage(on: indexPath) { //hide image}` is it right? **Second**. When Im in last cell and scroll right (horizontal scroll) my image showing. It happens if Im in first my cell and scroll left.